# Drag and create a new object in JS

Tags: javascript, svg

How can I create a SVG object that when you drag from it will create a new instance of it self.

Like if the first SVG object is at a fixed position and I try to drag it, it would create a new SVG object I can place where ever I want, while the first SVG object will still be at its start position.

Thanks :)

Comment: What have you tried so far? And have you found any resources by googling this?

Comment: I can drag and relocate my object, but cant make a new object from it.

Comment: Nice - could you please provide the code for that? It's easier for others to help you if some initial code is provided. Someone might still answer this, but the likelihood of an answer is way higher if there's something to work with.

Comment: thanks here :) https://jsfiddle.net/stephan_dd/a0t9cbkv/2/

Comment: the coordinates are just so I can keep track on the x-y position

Comment: Do you still need the clones to be draggable?

Comment: I created a solution based on your jsfiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/atfuzLso/1/). Let me know if this is what you expect then I turn it into an answer.

Comment: Thanks @Marius your awesome! the only thing I can point out is the first circle is the only one you can drag from, and the duplicates should be able to be dragged around :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created a solution based on the [HTML Drag and Drop API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API).

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/atfuzLso/145/

**HTML**

```
<div id="container" width="100%" height="100%">
  <div id="originalCircle" class="circle">
    <svg width='100' height='100'>
      <circle id='circleSvg' cx="50" cy="50" r="40"
              stroke="none" stroke-width="4" fill="rgb(185, 185, 185)" />
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var originalCircle = document.getElementById('originalCircle');
originalCircle.onmousedown = addCircle;

function addCircle(e) {
  var newCircle = originalCircle.cloneNode(true);
  newCircle.setAttribute("draggable", "true");
  newCircle.ondragstart = e => e.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain',null);

  var circleSvg = newCircle.querySelector('#circleSvg');
  circleSvg.setAttribute("fill", randomColor());

  var container = document.getElementById('container');
  container.appendChild(newCircle);
}

var draggedElmnt;
document.ondrag = e => {};

document.ondragstart = e => {
  draggedElmnt = e.target;
  draggedElmnt.offsetX = e.offsetX;
  draggedElmnt.offsetY = e.offsetY;
  draggedElmnt.style.opacity = 0.5;
}

document.ondragend = e => draggedElmnt.style.opacity = "";

document.ondrop = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  draggedElmnt.style.opacity = "";
  draggedElmnt.style.left = (e.clientX - draggedElmnt.offsetX) + "px";
  draggedElmnt.style.top = (e.clientY - draggedElmnt.offsetY) + "px";
}

document.ondragover = e => e.preventDefault(); // allow drop

function randomColor() {
  return "#"+((1<<24)*Math.random()|0).toString(16);
}
```

**CSS**

```
#container {
  position: relative;
}

.circle {
  position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: Thanks again, its perfect!